# Delete part of a value for the whole column

Tags: r, date

If a have a vector such as the following:

```
REF_YEAR
1994-01-01
1995-01-01
1996-01-01
```

how can I delete the part "-01-01", so that I only get the year for the whole column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your vector is formatted as `Date`s, you can do:

```
x <- as.Date("2001-01-01")
format(x, "%Y")
#[1] "2001"
```

And for your example data:

```
# Your sample data:
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text = "REF_YEAR
1994-01-01
1995-01-01
1996-01-01", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Convert your data to Date format:

```
df$REF_YEAR <- as.Date(df$REF_YEAR) # skip this step if it's already formatted as Date
```

Now convert to year format:

```
df$REF_YEAR <- format(df$REF_YEAR, "%Y")
```

Or

```
transform(df, REF_YEAR = format(REF_YEAR, "%Y"))
```

Result in both cases:

```
df
#  REF_YEAR
#1     1994
#2     1995
#3     1996
```

You only need to make sure your data is in `Date` format (use `as.Date()` for conversion).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using regular expression. You can either keep the first four digit or eliminate the last six. Here is how you can do using the second option as asked by you.

```
       ref_year = as.character("1994-01-01")
       ref_year_only = substr(ref_year, 1, nchar(ref_year) - 6) ; ref_year_only
```

Also, please show some effort while asking questions on stack.

Comment: @beginneR answer is more specific to your case. However my solution would work even if the vector is not a date.

Answer (score 0):

Without converting to `Date`, you could also try:

```
 library(stringr)
 df$YEAR <- str_extract(df$REF_YEAR, perl('\\d+(?=-)'))
 df$YEAR
 #[1] "1994" "1995" "1996"
```